# WPF ScrollViewer scrolling issue

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

I current making a small sample project to go through the UI "classes" scrollviewer seems to be really rough for me for some reason I can't seem to get this to scroll below is my layout.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="0"  Height="70" MinHeight="50px" MinWidth="400px" Dock="Top">
```

.....

```
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Grid>
              <Tree></Tree>
                </TreeView>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="RIGHT CONTENT" Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" />
                <TextBlock Text="Content goes here" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I'm not exactly sure why the stack panel won't scroll unless I add a definite height to the scroll viewer. If I do that the scroll viewer won't expand when I full screen or re size. I load a list into the tree on a click of a button, but no matter what layout I use it won't scroll.

This is also inside a Page that is navigated to from another window that only contains a Iframe.

Comment: Can you clarify whether your ScrollViewers are inside a Grid which isn't shown in your posted XAML? They have Row and Column values which won't do anything if their parent is the DockPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the VerticalScrollMode property to Enabled on your SrollViewers?

Comment: Yes what happens is it clips off my scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I mad a mistake in setting my overall layout in my main window where the page was to be place and it cause the content to not be scroll-able. I wrapped my frame in a grid and made row definitions and it worked.

Oh the joys of nested ui . . .